# ContentView wont bind global static value in Xamarin Forms

Tags: binding, xamarin.forms

I've got a problem in my `ContentView`:

I want to bind my `BackroundColor`to a Grid and a StackLayout

`BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:Const.Color_BackgroundNavigationBar}"`

This works very well in my `ContentPage`, but in my `ContentView` i got an error:

> Position 25:108. No property, bindable property, or event found for 'BackgroundColor'

The namespace for local is the same as in my ContentPage.
Is this a Problem which exists because of the ContentView or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution myself:
The `ContentView` was a Child of my `ContentPage` so I needed to set the Binding with the Source extra:

```
BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Static const:Const.Color_BackgroundNavigationBar}}"
```

Hope I interpreted the solution correct, now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The error basically says it all; a `ContentView` does not have a property `BackgroundColor`. See the [documentation page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ContentView/) for this type.

Comment: I havn't set the BackgroundColor property directly to the ContentView, I've used it for example on a Grid and a Stack Layout, i thought this shouldn't be a problem